# Raising the indices of the Hodge operator

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian $n$-manifold; $\mu$ is the volume form associated with $g$, and $\star$ is the Hodge operator induced by $\mu$.
Given a $k$-form $\beta$ on $M$, the $(n-k)$-multivector $B$ (alternating contravariant tensor on $M$) is obtained by raising the indices of $\star \beta$ with $g$.
Using components one has
$$\beta_{i_1...i_k}= \frac{1}{(n-k)!}\mu_{i_1...i_k \,i_{k+1} ... i_n}B^{i_{k+1} ...i_n} .$$
I was wondering if the operation $\beta\mapsto B$ has a specific name and what the most common notation is. I would guess $(\star\beta)^{\sharp}$, but maybe there is something more compact...